# Mouse for Sony Xperia Z4 Tablet

Tags: tablet, sony-xperia, mouse

I just bought a Sony Xperia Z4 Tablet. (Amazing BTW)  It has a keyboard and touchpad.

Can I add a wireless mouse to it?  What kind can I purchase that would work with Android/Sony's system?

I imagine it would be a bluetooth mouse, but I want to know even if I could connect the bluetooth device whether it would correctly drive the cursor on the tablet.

Example vendors/products would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please define "correctly drive"? What kind of functionality are you expecting from a Bluetooth mouse connected to your tablet?

Comment: Hi. I expect it to do the same as the Z4's keyboard touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

Simply [use USB mouse](https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/articles/SX367801).
It worked both for my Xperia Z4 tablet and my Xperia XZ phone. Tablet has to be turned off before mouse is connected (by pressing volume up + power button) while XZ phone seems to pick up external mouse without reboot.